# Is there any way to extend my visa?

Tags: visas, usa, covid-19, event-based-effects, mexican-citizens

I´m a Mexican citizen and my visa has expired. I was planning on taking some marketing courses in the USA in April, but with the pandemic, the consulate is closed. Is there any way to do the paperwork?

Comment: are you in the US and want to stay longer, or did you get a visa but not use it yet?

Comment: also, what type of visa do you have?